# Pyspark NLP - CountVectorizer Max DF or TF. How to filter common occurrences from dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, apache-spark-ml

I am using `CountVectorizer` to ready a dataset for ML. I want to filter out the rare words and I use the parameter of `CountVectorizer`, minDF or minTF for that. I would also like to remove items that appear 'often' in my dataset. I do not see a maxTF or maxDF parameter I can set. Is there a good way to do this?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(0, ["a", "b", "c","b"]), (1, ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])],
["label", "raw"])
```

So in this case if I wanted to remove parameters that appeared '4' times or 40% of the time, and, those that appeared 2 times or less. This would remove 'b' and 'c'.

Currently I run `CountVectorizer(minDf=3......)` for the lower bound req. How can I filter out the items that appear more often than I want to model on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you ask for CountVectorizer parameter but it looks like there is no parameter for that untill now. This is not a simple or practical way to do it in a simple but it works. I hope this help you:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(0, ["a", "b", "c","b"]), (1, ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])],
["label", "raw"])

counts_df = df \
    .select(F.explode('raw').alias('testCol')) \
    .groupby('testCol') \
    .agg(F.count('testCol').alias('count')).persist() # this will be used multiple times

total = counts_df \
    .agg(F.sum('count').alias('total')) \
    .rdd.take(1)[0]['total']
min_times = 3
max_times = total * 0.4
filtered_elements = counts_df \
    .filter((min_times>F.col('count')) | (F.col('count')>max_times)) \
    .select('testCol') \
    .rdd.map(lambda row: row['testCol']) \
    .collect()

def removeElements(arr):
    return list(set(arr) - set(filtered_elements))

remove_udf = F.udf(removeElements, ArrayType(StringType()))
filtered_df = df \
    .withColumn('raw', remove_udf('raw'))
```

Results:

```
filtered_df.show()
+-----+---+
|label|raw|
+-----+---+
|    0|[a]|
|    1|[a]|
+-----+---+
```